# google sheet: is there a cell character limit when using API to return data?

Tags: google-spreadsheets

I'm pulling data into a Google sheet via an API and it's working.

However, specifically one cell is for long description text and for some reason it's not displaying all the text. I've confirmed that the API is returning all the data so the issues appear to be on the Google Sheet side of things. 
It looks like the text is cut off at about 255 (253 in one case) characters (with spaces).

Is there a per cell character limit in google sheets specifically when using an API? If so is there any way around this? (because when I don't use an API it appears I can't have boatloads of characters)

Comment: Users should not cross-post questions. Instead they should flag their question for migration or wait for the community to do it. @Doug

Answer (score 0):

By default google sheets truncates the results to about 255 characters (with spaces). You can modify this by adding "notruncate" to your cell to resolve this.